# How do i pass arguments in the screens of drawernavigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

```
import {ProfileScreen} from './ProfileScreen';
import {DashboardScreen} from './DashboardScreen';
 import {
 DrawerNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator,
 createAppContainer,
 } from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {
createDrawerNavigator,
 DrawerNavigatorItems,
} from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import {NotificationScreen} from './NotificationScreen';


export class A_HomePage extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
header: null,
};
state = {
email: '',
 };

render() {

  this.setState({
    email: 'qwerty@gmail.com',
  });

return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
const ProfileStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
ProfileNavigator: ProfileScreen,
 },
{
defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
  return {
    headerLeft: (
      <Icon2
        style={{paddingLeft: 10}}
        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
        name="menu"
        size={30}
      />
    ),
  };
  },
 },
 );
 const NotificationScreenStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
 NotificationScreenNavigator: NotificationScreen,
 },
  {
 defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
  return {
    headerLeft: (
      <Icon2
        style={{paddingLeft: 10}}
        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
        name="menu"
        size={30}
      />
    ),
  };
  },
 },
);
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
{ Profile: {
  screen: ProfileStackNavigator,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: 'Profile',
    drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
      <Icon name="glass" size={25} color="#00b33c" />
    ),
  },
},Notification: {
  screen:NotificationScreenStackNavigator ,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: 'Notifications',
    drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
      <Icon4 name="notification" size={25} color="#cc0099" />
    ),
  },
},
 },);

 const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
{ 
Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen}, 
Notification: {screen:NotificationScreen},
 },);
 const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);
```

**
here i have created the two drawernavigation and homescreen contains all the stack of
drawernavigator screen  how do i pass this.state.email to the profile and notification screen of the drawernavigation or how can i access the states(here is email) in the screens profile and notification screens  pls help this can improve my project work i have searched it in google and docs but didnt got any idea  **

Comment: which library navigation you use?

Comment: react-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use React Redux with Redux

Redux is central state management system which also available for React-Native

[React Redux Getting Started](https://react-redux.js.org/)